# Get array value

Tags: array

I want to get a custom post value from post ID

PHP code :

```
$custom_field = get_post_meta(2055, the_field('titdesc'));
var_dump($custom_field);`
```

Output :

```
array(6) {
  ["_edit_last"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  ["_edit_lock"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(12) "1373450528:1"
  }
  ["_wp_page_template"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "work.php"
  }
  ["titdesc"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(34) "and some experience, coffee & fun."
  }
  ["_titdesc"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(19) "field_51baf57155c20"
  }
  ["dsq_thread_id"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
}
```

I want `["titdesc"]` value but not able to get what to write in PHP to get `["titdesc"]`'s value.

Comment: As a note, you should be using [`get_field()`](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/functions/get_field/) instead of `the_field()`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you messed up a bit. I'm assuming you're using the [ACF plugin](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) because you used [`the_field()`](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/functions/the_field/).

Have you tried only `the_field('titdesc');` if you're in the WordPress loop? Those functions already query values stored in your `postmeta` table. I'm assuming you have a field called `titdesc` since you're trying to read it using `the_field('titdesc')`.

If you're not in the loop, you must pass the post ID too, like `the_field('titdesc', 2055);`.

From what I've noticed, ACF uses two rows per custom field. For you it is:

- `titdesc` => `and some experience, coffee & fun.`
- `_titdesc` => `field_51baf57155c20`

The first pair of values stores the field name `titdesc` and the field value `and some experience, coffee & fun.` and the second pair of values is a reference to the field name's unique ID, which is `field_51baf57155c20` here.

As a note, [`get_field()`](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/functions/get_field/) will **return** a value and [`the_field()`](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/functions/the_field/) will **echo** the value.'

If you want to pass the value in a function, you should use `get_field()` instead.
What you got in your `var_dump()` output is all meta values stored for that particular post ID.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($array_name); //$custom_field in your case
echo "</pre>";
```

That generates a more understandable array dump.

Answer:

```
 echo $custom_field['titdesc'][0];
```

would do in your case.

or you can directly get a single meta key using

```
$titdesc = get_post_meta(2055, 'titdesc',true);
echo $titdesc;
```